# Running a Camera Sensor Headless

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

We are looking to run a camera sensor headless on a VM, however when we do so several of the camera's image topic (notably, `camera/image_raw`) are not published.  At ROSCon, I spoke briefly with Jose, who indicated that this could be done fairly painlessly, and is actually used for Gazebo's CI tests.  How would I go about enabling that capability?

To clarify, we already have a camera plugin that runs just fine on a display-enabled machine.  Our robot is defined in a URDF and launched using roslaunch.  However, note that the "headless" option exposed by `gazebo_ros_pkgs` doesn't actually work - see https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/491

I also don't see an explicit "headless" option list [in the Gazebo code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/192a57657ec0d4873f695a3dec026064aec0240e/gazebo/gazebo_main.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#gazebo_main.cc-45:68).  The Gazebo devs did mention that such a mode was possible, I just can't figure out how.

(Running Gazebo 7 and ROS Indigo)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14625/running-a-camera-sensor-headless/) by [JLiviero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2765/jliviero/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks guys.  I've got a solution, which I'll post here for the benefit of anyone else who comes searching for such a thing later.

Because our VMs aren't running NVidia drivers as a rule, I wanted to explore some other options before attempting Jose's solution.  Based on Nate and Jose's comments, I went digging into virtual xservers and found
[this old comment](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2153/drcsim-cant-figure-out-how-to-run-gazebo-on-remote-machine-and-get-vision-input/?answer=2159#post-id-2159), which led me to Xvfb.  With Xvfb, I was able to do the following:

```
$ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &
$ export DISPLAY=:1.0
$ roslaunch etc etc.launch
```

...which let me run the camera plugin headlessly on a VM with no problems.  Here's a screen grab from the camera, taken remotely by connecting RQT to the robot on the VM:

[image: image description]

([This timely Gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1837/vmware-rendering-z-ordering-appears-random) fix was also helpful.)

Thanks again!

---

Originally posted by [JLiviero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2765/jliviero/) with karma: 94 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GL](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3005/gl/) on 2017-01-12**:
This solution worked with my launch file. Thank you for sharing your fix!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think it can be done by running the Gazebo server in Headless mode with the following command

```
gzserver  # then you can use gz topic -l to verify it is running
```

By default it doesn't have a camera sensor, so you will have to define your own world SDF file with a camera sensor.

The rest is up to you.

---

Originally posted by [chutsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/482/chutsu/) with karma: 36 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JLiviero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2765/jliviero/) on 2016-10-24**:
As I noted in the question, we already have a camera plugin that runs just fine on a display-enabled machine.  Our robot is defined in a URDF and launched using roslaunch.  I should have been more clear, sorry - I've updated my original question accordingly.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-10-25**:
`gzserver` runs headless. Your machine will need an xserver running if you want to render camera data.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Jordan:

As Nate has mentioned in the comments, you will need an xserver running to be able to render camera data. In order to have an xserver running with a headless setup and assuming that you are using an Nvidia card, you could use ([starting with 331.* driver series](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/585014/how-to-configure-x-server-to-work-headless-as-well-with-any-monitor-connected-/)):

`nvidia-xconfig --allow-empty-initial-configuration`

This should generate the following configuration in your Xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    ...
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    ...
EndSection
```

Hope it helps. Thanks for sharing the feedback in the ROSCon!

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsather](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5441/jsather/) on 2018-08-28**:
Hi Jose,

For this to work, do you also need to set up a display server like Xvfb? I am trying to run Gazebo on a Google Compute Engine instance running Ubuntu 16.04 with an Nvidia K80 GPU and have yet to get it working. If you are willing to take a look, I included a few more details in my StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050708/how-to-run-gazebo-on-google-compute-engine-with-gpu